# Need help for writting test class for method for extention controller

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, contentversion, contentdocument

Sorry I am new with salesforce developer. I have written method for extension controller. I need help with writing test class for that method. with that method what it does is visualforce is renderas pdf and that visualforce is gets attach to files related object for that account.

```
<public pageReference savePDF(){
    if(doSave == 'No'){ return null; }
     PageReference pagePdf = new PageReference('/apex/BAR_ctrl_Test');
     pagePdf.getParameters().put('id', acct.Id);
     pagePdf.getParameters().put('doSave', 'No');
     Blob pdfPageBlob;
     pdfPageBlob = pagePdf.getContentAsPDF();
     Date d = Date.Today() ;
     String dateStr =  d.format() ;
    List<ContentDocumentLink> docList = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :acct.Id];

    Set<Id> CDLs = new Set<Id>();
    for (ContentDocumentLink docLink : docList) {
        CDLs.add(docLink.ContentDocumentId);
    }
    string onepage='One Pager '+dateStr;

    List<ContentVersion> files = [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocument.Id, ContentDocument.ContentSize, ContentDocument.FileType, ContentDocument.Description
                                  FROM ContentVersion 
                                  WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :CDLs and Title like :onepage ];       
    // Create Document into PDF
     ContentVersion  a = new ContentVersion();
     a.versionData = pdfPageBlob;
     a.ContentLocation = 'S';
     a.Title = 'One Pager '+dateStr;
     a.PathOnClient = '/acct.id.pdf';
     a.isMajorVersion= false;       
    if(files.isempty()){    
        insert a;
        ContentVersion acctContent = [SELECT id,FirstPublishLocationId, ContentDocumentId,title FROM ContentVersion where Id = :a.Id];
        ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentlink.LinkedEntityId= acct.id;
        contentlink.ShareType= 'V';
        contentlink.ContentDocumentId=acctcontent.ContentDocumentId;
        insert contentlink;  
    }else{            
        for(ContentVersion k: files){
            k.versionData = pdfPageBlob;
            k.Title = 'One Pager '+dateStr;
        }
        update files;
    }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Hello Rahul, welcome to SFSE. Code coverage is one of the most common questions we receive. Have you had a chance to complete the [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro) on this subject, review any of the [3,000+ existing questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-test) on unit tests, or review resources like the [Salesforce Developer Blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/why-we-test.html) or [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)?

Comment: Please be aware that SFSE is not a code-writing service, and your questions need to meet some [expectations](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) about specificity, detail, and showing your own work.

Comment: Yes. I have complete it but I have never work with contentversion and contentdocument before. So that is why i needed help. for writing test class for it.

Answer (score 2):

> At least 75% of your Apex code must be covered by unit tests, and all of those tests must complete successfully.
>   Note the following.
>   When deploying Apex to a production organization, each unit test in your organization namespace is executed by default.
>   Calls to System.debug are not counted as part of Apex code coverage.
>   Test methods and test classes are not counted as part of Apex code coverage.
>   While only 75% of your Apex code must be covered by tests, your focus shouldn't be on the percentage of code that is covered. Instead, you should make sure that every use case of your application is covered, including positive and negative cases, as well as bulk and single records. This should lead to 75% or more of your code being covered by unit tests.
>   Every trigger must have some test coverage.
>   All classes and triggers must compile successfully.

Best practise:-

1. If code uses conditional logic (including ternary operators),
   execute each branch.
2. Make calls to methods using both valid and invalid inputs.
3. Complete successfully without throwing any exceptions, unless those
   errors are expected and caught in a try…catch block.
4. Always handle all exceptions that are caught, instead of merely
   catching the exceptions.
5. Use System.assert methods to prove that code behaves properly.
6. Use the runAs method to test your application in different user
   contexts.
7. Exercise bulk trigger functionality—use at least 20 records in your
   tests.
8. Use the ORDER BY keywords to ensure that the records are returned in
   the expected order.
9. Not assume that record IDs are in sequential order.
10. Set up test data:
11. Create the necessary data in test classes, so the tests do not have
     to rely on data in a particular organization.
12. Create all test data before calling the Test.startTest method.
13. Since tests don't commit, you won't need to delete any data.
14. Write comments stating not only what is supposed to be tested, but
     the assumptions the tester made about the data, the expected outcome, and so on. Test the classes in your application individually. Never test your entire application in a single test.

**I am just giving an overview so that you can understand:-**

Step 1-> You need to create a test class with @isTest annotation

```
@isTest
public class TestDataFactory {
    public static void createTestRecords() {
}
}
```

step 2--> Now you need to create the Test data in inside your test method. Also, You should create a  user and run your test in that user context.

```
String uniqueUserName = 'standarduser' + DateTime.now().getTime() + '@testorg.com';
        // This code runs as the system user
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com',
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
         UserName=uniqueUserName);

System.runAs(u) {
        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestAccount');
        insert acc;

        ContentVersion  a = new ContentVersion();
             a.versionData = blob.valueof('testdata');
             a.ContentLocation = 'S';
             a.Title = 'OnePage';
             a.PathOnClient = 'OnePage.pdf';
        insert a;

        ContentVersion cv=[select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where id=:a.id];

        ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
                contentlink.LinkedEntityId= acc.id;
                contentlink.ShareType= 'V';
                contentlink.ContentDocumentId=cv.ContentDocumentId;
                insert contentlink;
```

your apex class is used as an extension of the Visualforce page, You can write inside Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest():-

```
Test.startTest()
PageReference pageRef = Page.yourpage;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
pageRef.getParameters().put('Id',acc.id);
yourClassName objCtrl = new yourClassName();
objCtrl.savePDF();
Test.stopTest()
```

Hope it helps you.